# Translation of "Made in city/country/year" in latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How should I translate "Made in Rome" and "Made in 2022" in latin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you typically see on inscriptions is the person who made it, *me*, and *fecit*. People took ownership of their craft back then, as opposed to mass produced things today.

But since presumably you don't who the person who crafted your object, we can use the passive, which would be *factus, -a, -um est*. For example, "this thing was made" equates to *Hoc factum est.* (See for example [this manuscript](https://www.bl.uk/catalogues/illuminatedmanuscripts/record.asp?MSID=3553&CollID=8&NStart=176)).

Denoting the year is as simple as writing *anno* (ablative of *annus* meaning "year") followed by the year in Roman numerals. So *Hoc anno MMXXII* factum est.*

For location, you do have more options, but generally for countries you'll simply use *in* plus the ablative. With Rome in particular (and other cities) you'll have to use the locative, *Romae*.

> **Hoc Romae anno MMXXII factum est.**
> This thing was made at Rome in 2022.

Comment: If I only want "Made in 2022", How about "Hoc MMXXII AD factum est"?

ref. https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4483/translation-of-since-1950-for-example

Comment: @James Yeah, that works. AD is an abbreviation for *anno domini*, so feel free to spell that out in full instead of abbreviating, and place it before the numbers as well.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning, anno MMXXII is actually *anno bis millesimo vicesimo secundo* = the two thousandth and twenty second year. Just in case you want to read it out ...

Comment: Is it possible to make "Hoc MMXXII AD factum est" shorter?

Comment: You can leave out *hoc* and *est* if you want.

Comment: So it can be "MMXXII AD factum"?

Comment: @James If you're going to do that, I would probably reorder the words: *Factum AD MMXXII.* AD goes before the date.

Comment: That's interesting.

So with hoc and est, AD can go after the date, but without hoc and est, AD should go before date?

Comment: @James No, AD should go first regardless. This is true in English, too.

Comment: @cmw Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel Thank you also!

Comment: @James You're welcome. If this answers your question completely, remember to vote up and select the green check mark to mark it answered.

Comment: How about, *factum sum*?